# Unable to run python code in Zeppelin on Windows Server

Tags: python, apache-zeppelin

I could configure Zeppelin on my windows server 2019 and successfully start it.

My environment variable is Configured as follows:

```
HADOOP_HOME C:\hadoop\
JAVA_HOME   C:\Programm Files\Zulu\zulu-8\jre\
SPARK_HOME  C:\Saprk\spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3\
```

But I would like to run a very simple Python code in my Zeppelin notebook. Ad I have set up the Python like this:
[image]

So now if I execute the following code:

```
%python
print("Hello World")
```

I get the following error message:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch interpreter process:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-netinst/interpreter/python/python-interpreter-with-py4j-0.10.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-netinst/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.main(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:305)

 

    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:129)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:271)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:438)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch interpreter process:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-netinst/interpreter/python/python-interpreter-with-py4j-0.10.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-netinst/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.main(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:305)

 

    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ExecRemoteInterpreterProcess.start(ExecRemoteInterpreterProcess.java:97)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:68)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(RemoteInterpreter.java:104)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:154)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:126)
    ... 13 more
Took 1 minute. Last updated by anonymous at June 27 2023, 2:10:45 PM.
ERROR
%sh
echo 1
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch interpreter process:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-netinst/interpreter/sh/zeppelin-shell-0.10.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-netinst/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.main(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:305)

 

    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:129)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:271)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:438)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Fail to launch interpreter process:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-netinst/interpreter/sh/zeppelin-shell-0.10.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-netinst/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.main(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:305)

 

    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ExecRemoteInterpreterProcess.start(ExecRemoteInterpreterProcess.java:97)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ManagedInterpreterGroup.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(ManagedInterpreterGroup.java:68)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getOrCreateInterpreterProcess(RemoteInterpreter.java:104)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:154)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:126)
    ... 13 more
```

I found this [post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-5508) that someone has the same problem with Java interpreter and could solve the problem, but the solution doesn't work for Python.

Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin Only Version <= 0.8.2 support windows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).